# why pressing M in linux's top command will have many processes that does not exist?

Tags: linux, memory, top

i pressed M in top command try to get a memory sort for the processes,

```
5892 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:01   0 java
 5893 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   6:47   0 java
 5894 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:00   0 java
 5895 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:00   0 java
 5896 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:00   0 java
 5897 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:03   0 java
 5898 myuser   15   0 88428  86M 12520 S     0.0  4.2   0:00   0 java
```

however, i actually do not have that many java process, 
ps -ef |grep java
only give 2 results, one is a true java process and the other is my ps command;

is there a way to get current's process's memory usage?
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to also press `H` this will make top show individual threads.

Comment: no, i do not; just tried once again, it's still the same;